# Why can't function declaration be accessed after enclosed in parentheses?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

The function declaration can no longer be accessed by its name:

```js
(function log(){
  console.log('print some information')
})
log()
```

The code throw reference error. My understanding with that is: function `log` doesn't live in any inner scope, why can't I call it by its name?

Comment: when you enclose a function like that it is run under its own executing scope. meaning that it will run the function after it is read by the javascript engine.

Comment: Why are you enclosing that function in parentheses? What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen usually that's why a function instantiation is parenthesized, but in this case there is no `()` to call the function (except for the place where it won't work).

Comment: @Pointy the correct format is `(function(){ /*code here */ })();`

Comment: @Pointy called [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen yes thanks, I know that. That's not what's being attempted in this question; it's about how (well, where) the name given after the `function` keyword is bound.

Comment: @Pointy, when you create a wrapped function like the IIFE, the code, functions and variables are in their own special scope. meaning that you can't access it, however, jquery does something like this where they will assign jquery to the window variable like [this](https://pastebin.com/N4Ssgygp)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen parentheses do not create a scope on their own, and again, because there is no *invocation*, it's not an IIFE ("Immediately Invoked Function Expression"). The issue is that the function name in a function *instantiation expression* is only bound as a reference to the function *inside* the created function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why can't I call it by its name?

When you put parenthesis around your `function`, you get a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), and not a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), as the parser expects to see an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping#description) between the `()` and not a declaration. Function expressions names can only be accessed locally to that function:

> If you want to refer to the current function inside the function body,
> you need to create a named function expression. **This name is then
> local only to the function body (scope)**
>
> - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#named_function_expression)

The same applies for other operators such as `!` and `+`, not just `()`, which makes your function be treated as a function expression.

If you were wanting to make a function *declaration*, you can remove the parenthesis:

```js
function log(){
  console.log('print some information');
}
log();
```

Comment: Thanks, bro, I got it. Since there is no function declaration inside of the parentheses, How can I still invoke that function in a declaration way

Comment: @Aibin the last code snippet example shows how you can make a function declaration and then invoke it.